# How to read a TimeStamp datetime2(2) from a Sql database into Groovy

Tags: sql, datetime, groovy, getter-setter

I am trying to read a TimeStamp datetime2(2) from a SQL server database which is  in the format '**2017-05-05 07:00:15.04**'. I get a formatting error in my groovy while executing.

i Have used as follows:

```
private DateTime Time_TimeStamp;

....
// getter and setters///

public DateTime getTime_TimeStamp() {
        return Time_TimeStamp;
    }
    public void setTime_TimeStamp(DateTime time_TimeStamp) {
        Time_TimeStamp = time_TimeStamp;
```

The error i receive is :
FL_DPG_TimeAD.setTime_TimeStamp() is applicable for argument types: (java.sql.Timestamp) values: [2017-05-05 07:00:15.04]
Possible solutions: setTime_TimeStamp(long), getTime_TimeStamp()

How can i use exact datetime2(2) which is in format in groovy ?

Comment: please edit your question and specify what sql database are you using, what error message do you have.

Comment: @daggett : I have edited my question. The error i receive is FL_DPG_TimeAD.setTime_TimeStamp() is applicable for argument types: (java.sql.Timestamp) values: [2017-05-05 07:00:15.04] Possible solutions: setTime_TimeStamp(long), getTime_TimeStamp()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error

> `FL_DPG_TimeAD.setTime_TimeStamp()` is applicable for argument types: `(java.sql.Timestamp)` values: `[2017-05-05 07:00:15.04]`
>
> Possible solutions: `setTime_TimeStamp(long)`, `getTime_TimeStamp()`

means that
the method  `setTime_TimeStamp` in your object `FL_DPG_TimeAD` accepts `long` but you try to pass into this method `java.sql.Timestamp`

you just have to find a way to convert `Timestamp` to `long`

check the documentation for [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

there is a method `getTime()` that returns timestamp as a long value